# Can I create more than one Twilio Composition Setting for 2 different projects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, twilio, twilio-video

I have 2 projects where I am saving videos in Twilio. One project, I do not want to change. The second project, I want to move the storage to S3. I have 2 buckets in S3, `bucket1` and `bucket2`, and I would like to store the videos from some of my application users in `bucket1`, and to store videos from others in `bucket2`. I've seen [this Twilio documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/external-s3-compositions) that I can configure the `aws_s3_url` in Twilio Composition Settings, but the url is always `"https://video.twilio.com/v1/CompositionSettings/Default"`. I do not want to change the Default settings, because I do not want the storage settings for my first project to change. Also, for my second project, I want to create 2 new settings which have the different S3 buckets, so they cannot be the same Composition Setting.

Is there a way that I can create 2 new composition settings with urls like `"https://video.twilio.com/v1/CompositionSettings/Settings1"` and `"https://video.twilio.com/v1/CompositionSettings/Settings2"`, so that I can not "mess up" the default Composition Settings, and also have 2 separate s3 storage buckets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you administer your projects as different [projects or subaccounts](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011132374-Getting-Started-with-Twilio-Projects-and-Subaccounts) then you can set the `aws_s3_url` separately for them.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for :)  Just to check, setting the `aws_s3_url` for a subaccount won't change the `aws_s3_url` for the project, right?

Comment: Projects and subaccounts are separated by Account SIDs. If you set the `aws_s3_url` for one Account SID, it will not change it for resources under a different Account SID.